# spyder not running kivy script properly but IDLE does

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, spyder

I am trying to execute the below python script using spyder IDE (version 3.3.0). I am new to kivy so still trying to get a hang of it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (200, 100)

class Test_Screen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test_Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rows = 2
        test_label = Label(text='Hello, world', color=(1, 0, 0, 1))
        self.add_widget(test_label)
        test_button = Button(text='Button', color=(1, 0, 0, 1))
        self.add_widget(test_button)

class Test_Kivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test_Screen()

kivy_object = Test_Kivy()
kivy_object.run()
```

The program runs successfully the first time. But when I try to execute it the second time, I get an error. Below is a complete screenshot of both the first and second runs as seen in spyder's `Console 1/A`.

*First execution (ran successfully):*

```
runfile('D:/SIPRA/Programs/kivy_test.py', wdir='D:/SIPRA/Programs')
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\SIPRA\.kivy\logs\kivy_18-07-22_68.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
Purge log fired. Analysing...
Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 398.36'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'NVIDIA Corporation'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'GeForce GTX 1080 Ti/PCIe/SSE2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 NVIDIA'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <32768>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

*Immediate second execution (throws error):*

```
runfile('D:/SIPRA/Programs/kivy_test.py', wdir='D:/SIPRA/Programs')
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR  ] [Base        ] No event listeners have been created
[ERROR  ] [Base        ] Application will leave
```

The same code runs without any error each and every time when I try executing it from IDLE. I am using Python 3.7 64 bit and my OS is Windows 10 (64 bit). The spyder version is 3.3.0. Kivy version is V1.10.1. I have looked at the problem raised in this SO thread - "[Spyder not running Kivy script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49205744/spyder-not-running-kivy-script)", but it was for an older version of spyder and the error seems to be different from what I am encountering. Hence posting a new question. Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We don't have the time nor the resources to support Kivy users (we're heavily oriented towards scientific/data analysis workflows). So I think you'd be better by using a different IDE.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that could help in this case is deactivating the Graphics support in our consoles. For that you need to go to `Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics`, deactivating the option called `Activate support` and starting a new console.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I do understand your constraints. I have been using IDLE and it works fine for this scenario. However, I am not a kivy user, but a very heavy spyder user.. :-)

Comment: Did things work by deactivating the Graphics support?

Comment: Hey Carlos, I deactivated `Active support` as per your suggestion. But I am still getting the same error as specified in my question. The program runs successfully the first time it is executed. When I simply re-execute the entire code again without doing anything else, I get the error message. Sorry, I should have mentioned this earlier. It works successfully even if executed multiple times without any error in IDLE.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas.